# f whose second-order partial derivatives are continuous

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} ^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ whose second-order  partial derivatives are continuous, if $\int_C ( \frac{∂f}{∂y}dx - \frac{∂f}{∂x} dy ) = 0 $ for any closed curve simple $C$ then $ ∇^2 f(x,y) = 0$ $ \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} ^2$

My teacher explained the proof of this theorem in class but i did not understand his proof someone can explain to me in detail, please. It´s really important to me  understand this for solve exercise.

Comment: So, that means $f$ is harmonic.

Comment: It's conservative since it is zero over all closed curves, so we have $F_x=f_y$ and $F_y=-f_x$. Therefore $F_{xx}=f_{yx}$ and $F_{yy}=-f_{xy}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)

> $$ 
>     \oint_{C} (L\, dx + M\, dy) = \iint_{D} \left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)\, dx\, dy . $$

For your case, we have

> $$ L =\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} ,\quad M = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $$

Can you finish the problem?

**Note:**

> $$ ∇^2 f(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}. $$

Comment: well here is my problem i try again solve the double integral but how can apply that the curve is simple and closed?

Comment: ∂M/∂x-∂L/∂y = -(∂^2f/∂x^2+∂^2f/∂y^2) =0 is that correct? then the integral of ∂M/∂x-∂L/∂y = -(∂^2f/∂x^2+∂^2f/∂y^2) =0 is that correct? but why is zero?